# Array written as name[x, y] rather than name[x][y]

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

What is the difference between the two syntaxes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one is a multi dimensional array while the second is a jagged array.  You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c) to get a description of the diffrerence between the two, but here is an important snippit:

> A multidimensional array creates a nice linear memory layout while a
>   jagged array implies several extra levels of indirection.
>
> Looking up the value jagged[3][6] in a jagged array var jagged = new
>   int[10][5] works like this: Look up the element at index 3 (which is
>   an array) and look up the element at index 6 in that array (which is a
>   value). For each dimension in this case, there's an additional look up
>   (this is an expensive memory access pattern).
>
> A multidimensional array is laid out linearly in memory, the actual
>   value is found by multiplying together the indexes. However, given the
>   array var mult = new int[10,30] the Length property of that
>   multidimensional array returns the total number of elements i.e. 10 *
>   30 = 300.
>
> The Rank property of a jagged array is always 1, but a
>   multidimensional array can have any rank. The GetLength method of any
>   array can be used to get the length of each dimension. For the
>   multidimensional array in this example mult.GetLength(1) returns 30.
>
> Indexing the multidimensional array is faster e.g. given the
>   multidimensional array in this example mult[1,7] = 30 * 1 + 7 = 37,
>   get the element at that index 37. This is a better memory access
>   pattern because only one memory location is involved, which is the
>   base address of the array.
>
> A multidimensional array therefore allocates a continuous memory
>   block, while a jagged array does not have to be square like. e.g.
>   jagged[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c).Length does not have to equal jagged[2].Length which would
>   be true for any multidimensional array.

Update:

One major difference between the multi and jagged array is that a multi must always be "square", meaning that any two indexes will have the same number of elements in their child arrays.  A jagged array does not have this requirement.  Take a look at the code below:

```
var jagged = new int[3][]; //not defining the size of the child array...
var multi = new int[3,8]; //defining a 3x8 "square"
var multiBad = new int[3,]; //Syntax error!
var jaggedSquare= new int[3][8]; //another 3x8 "square"
```

Comment: but they both essentially do the same thing? as far as using them is concerned I mean (on a shallow level)

Comment: On the other hand, a jagged array may be sparse, saving memory and improving locality over a multidimensional array.

Comment: @SirYakalot, not exactly.  Take a look at myupdate

Answer (score 2):

The former is a two dimensional array.  The latter is an array whose elements are also arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The first is for a multidimentional array

the second is for array of arrays